# I define a Property on User Class,But I can't Get It's Value on Login Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

> Define Property

[image]

> Try Get Value

[image]

I don't know what I should be doing,I have to use department Repository get the value?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need to call Include method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, it is caused by that `GetLoginResultAsync` which calls `LoginAsync` did not load your `Department navigation property`.

For a workaround, you could requery `User` by `IRepository<User, long> _userRepository` with `loginResult.User.Id` like below:

```
_userRepository.GetAllIncluding(u => u.Claims,
                                u => u.CreatorUser,
                                u => u.DeleterUser,
                                u => u.Roles,
                                u => u.Department).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id ==loginResult.User.Id);
```